# Send Email from my vb .net windows form

Tags: email, send

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps8Kv.png)when I send Email from my vb .net windows form than an error occur
i think there is some authentication problem..
MailBox Unavailable.The Server Response Was:5.7.3 
Requested Action Aborted;
User Not Authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Correo As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        Dim SMTP As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

        Correo.From = "VALID EMAIL FROM"

        Correo.To.Add("VALID EMAIL TO)

        Correo.Subject = "Subject text"

        Correo.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal
        Correo.IsBodyHtml = True
        Correo.Body = "BODY OF EMAIL"

        Correo.Attachments.Add("DIRECTORY FROM FILE TO ATTACH")

        SMTP.Host = "VALID SMTP"
        SMTP.Port = "VALID PORT"

        SMTP.EnableSsl = "SSL TRUE OR FALSE"
        SMTP.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user name", "password")
        SMTP.DeliveryMethod = Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

        Dim Token As Object = Correo

        AddHandler SMTP.SendCompleted, AddressOf SmtpClient_OnCompleted

        SMTP.SendAsync(Correo, Token)

        ' Wait response from SmtpClient_OnCompleted

    End Sub

    Public Sub SmtpClient_OnCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)

    End Sub
```